# Slicing a list specially

Tags: list, python-3.x, slice

How would I get the last three elements of a list, not including the first element?

For example, with these two lists

`a = ['Matt', '1', '2']` , `b = ['Luke', '1', '2', '3']`

I would want the returned lists to be: `['1', '2']` and `['1', '2', '3']`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: How is `['1', '2']` the *last 3 elements* ?

Comment: It's the last three elements not including the first element. All the lists are in the format `['name', 'score', 'score'..]` and I need the last three 'score' elements, not including 'name'.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) for this:

```
>>> b[-3:]
['1', '2', '3']
```

If you have less than 3 scores in your list then you can:

```
>>> b = ['Luke', '1', '2']
>>> b[1:]
['1', '2']
```

So to combine them you can use:

```
if len(b) > 3:
    b[-3:]
else:
    b[1:]
```

Comment: But that returns all the elements after the first. If I have a list in this format: `['n', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], I need it to return ['3', '4', '5'], not ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'].

Comment: I fixed this @Matt

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the *last* `n` elements from a list, you do:

```
a[-n:]
```

---

Here's a quick example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[-3:]
[2, 3, 4]
```

If your list contains < n elements, you can just slice the first element out.

Answer (score 1):

In your case name is always first parameter in lists, so just apply on each of one of them:

```
 a = a[1:]
 b = b[1:]
```

Getting last three parameters won't work on a, since it contains 3 parameters. It will work after some condition statements.

If you're sure you want last 3 parameters use this:

```
a = a[-3:]
b = b[-3:]
```

Full snippet for you:

```
def get_list(my_list):
    if len(my_list) > 3:
        return my_list[-3:]
    else:
        return my_list[1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other good answers, you may want to consider using [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead of lists for this. You can do it like so:

```
a = ['Matt', '1', '2']
b = ['Luke', '1', '2', '3']
scoresDict = {}

scoresDict[a[0]] = a[1:]
scoresDict[b[0]] = b[1:]

print(scoresDict)
print(scoresDict['Matt'])
print(scoresDict['Luke'])
```

Output:

```
{'Matt': ['1', '2'], 'Luke': ['1', '2', '3']}
['1', '2']
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

For varying elements in the `list`, put all of those in a list and `map` it to a `lambda` function.

```
In [1]: a = [1,2,3,4]
In [2]: b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
In [3]: lis = [a, b]

In [4]: list(map(lambda x: x[-(len(x)-1):], lis))
Out[4]: [[2, 3, 4], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
```